# Python ValueError while dividing array by its own column

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

`Numpy` arrays `A = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4 ]]` and `C = A[:,1]`. B should be A/C. I am expecting `B to be [[0.5, 1, 1.5, 2], [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2]]` I am trying to do the same using normal division, or `numpy` division, but get an error, `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,4) (2,)`. It is dividing an entire array with a column in that particular array. Any suggestions? There is a similar post, but no solid answers to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make broadcasting possible here add one more axis to `C`:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4 ]], dtype=float)
>>> C = A[:,1][:, None]
>>> A/C
array([[ 0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ],
       [ 0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ]])
```

Answer (score 3):

[NumPy broadcasts](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) by adding new axes on the left. If you want to add a new axis on the right, you must do so manually:

```
B = A/C[:, np.newaxis]
```

`A` has shape `(2,4)` and `C` has shape `(2,)`. We need `C` to have shape `(2,4)` for `A/C` to make sense. If we add a new axis on the right-hand-side to `C`, then `C` would have shape `(2,1)` which NumPy then broadcasts to shape `(2,4)` upon division with `A`.

---

```
In [73]: A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]])

In [74]: C = A[:,1]

In [75]: A.shape
Out[75]: (2, 4)

In [76]: C.shape
Out[76]: (2,)

In [77]: B = A/C[:, np.newaxis]

In [78]: B
Out[78]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 1, 2]])
```

As [NumPy broadcasts](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) by adding new axes on the left. If you want to add a new axis on the right, you must do so manually:

```
B = A/C[:, np.newaxis]
```

`A` has shape `(2,4)` and `C` has shape `(2,)`. We need `C` to have shape `(2,4)` for `A/C` to make sense. If we add a new axis on th right-hand-side to C, then `C` would have shape `(2,1)` which NumPy then broadcasts to shape `(2,4)` upon division with `A`.

---

```
In [73]: A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4 ]])

In [74]: C = A[:,1]

In [75]: A.shape
Out[75]: (2, 4)

In [76]: C.shape
Out[76]: (2,)

In [77]: B = A/C[:, np.newaxis]

In [78]: B
Out[78]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 1, 2]])
```

As Ashwini Chaudhary shows, convert `A` (or `C`) to a float dtype to make NumPy perform floating-point division:

```
In [113]: A.astype(float)/C[:, np.newaxis]
Out[113]: 
array([[ 0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ],
       [ 0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ]])
```